# HTML Email not contained within defined width

Tags: html, email, outlook

I have clearly defined the width of my email to be 804px wide max. But within Outlook it will full screen width the whole thing, can't tell if it's a specific element somewhere not taking into account the max width. Trying to see if anyone can see an obvious reason for this.

It looks like the left content text is the issue but I have defined width for that too!

Looks fine within a browser of course! Dam email programs (Outlook).

Screenshot of what it looks like in Outlook.
[image]

HTML Email Code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>WYLES HARDY & Co</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width = 483" />
<style type="text/css">
a {text-decoration:none; color: #004466; }
a img, img, .images, .images a, .images a img, .images img { border: 0; padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body {width: 100% !important; background-color: #fff; font-family: 'Arial'; }

p { margin: 10px 5px 0px 5px; line-height: 19px; font-size: 14px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #004466; }
p.larger { margin: 5px 5px 8px 5px; line-height: 19px; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #004466; }
p a { color: #00A952; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; }

h1 { margin: 5px; color: #00405C; font-weight: bold; font-size: 18px; }
h2 { margin: 10px 5px 10px 5px; color: #00405C; font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px; } 
.blue-table { background: #EAF0F4; margin: 0; padding: 0 10px 10px 10px; border: 0; }
.clear-table { background: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; }
.grid-table { border: 1px solid #004466; margin: 5px; line-height: 20px; font-size: 11px; font-family: 'Arial'; color: #004466; }
.table-div { width: 96%; margin: 2%; height: 1px; border-top: 1px solid #004466; }

.left { text-align: left;}
.right { text-align: right; }

.main { border: 1px solid #444; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; padding: 5px; }
.content { background: #fff; }
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0">
<a name="top"></a>
<table class="main" width="804px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>

            <table width="804px" class="images">
                <tr><td><a target="_blank" href="http://www.wyleshardy.com/businesssales.asp?pge=3"><img style="border: 0; padding: 0" src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/header.jpg" /></a></td></tr>
            </table>            
            <br />

            <table width="804px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="clear-table" width="20px"><img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/10px-spacer.jpg" /></td>


                        <td class="clear-table" width="395px" valign="top" >
                            <table class="clear-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>                            
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="http://www.wyleshardy.com/businesssales.asp?pge=3">
                                        <!-- <ul width="405px">
                                            <li>Company established over 30 years ago.</li>
                                            <li>Trades from NW London from leased industrial premises.</li>
                                            <li>Offers various printing products and services including office stationery, litho printing (44%), digital printing (22%), promotional products and mail fulfilment and dispatch services (34%).</li>
                                            <li>The company has a diverse number of clients, together with a significant business relationship with a high profile client group, forged over many years.</li>
                                            <li>It holds ISO 9001 Certification for quality management and also FSC and PEFC accreditations.</li>
                                            <li>It has a dedicated and loyal workforce, with employees currently totaling 23, including 4 directors.</li>
                                            <li>The business and assets include goodwill (name, web domains, client data base, telephone numbers etc.) Contracts, various items of plant &amp; machinery (some subject to finance agreements), and minimal stock.</li>
                                        </ul> -->
                                        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&bull;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;Company established over 30 years ago.</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&bull;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;Trades from NW London from leased industrial premises.</td>
                                          </tr>
                                          <tr>
                                            <td>&bull;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;Offers various printing products and services including office stationery, litho printing (44%), digital printing (22%), promotional products and mail fulfilment and dispatch services (34%).</td>
                                          </tr>
                                        </table>
                                        </a>
                                        <a href="http://www.wyleshardy.com/businesssales.asp?pge=3"><img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/frplogo.jpg" width="375px" alt="" title="" /></a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>                           

                        </td>                        

                        <td class="clear-table" width="10px"><img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/10px-spacer.jpg" /></td>

                        <td class="content" width="346px" valign="top">
                            <table class="blue-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><a href="http://www.wyleshardy.com/businesssales.asp?pge=3">
                                    <p><strong>TURNOVER:</strong> Turnover totalled &pound;2.8m per accounts to June 2013, and &pound; 1.9m for the 9 months to March 2014.</p>
                                    <p><strong>OPPORTUNITIES:</strong> The Company offers an excellent opportunity to consolidate existing trade and exploit the contracts already in place.</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <h1>ENQUIRIES:</h1>
                                    <p class="larger">All enquiries should<br>be directed to:<br>
                                    <strong>Julie Gearing<br>Nigel Strike<br>FRP Advisory LLP</strong></p>
                                    <p><strong>Tel:</strong> 01277 503 304<br><strong>Fax:</strong> 01277 503 300<br><strong>Email:</strong><br> Julie.Gearing@frpadvisory.com<br>Nigel.Strike@frpadvisory.com</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p><strong>FRP Advisory LLP</strong><br>Jupiter House<br>Warley Hill Business Park<br>The Drive<br>Brentwood<br>Essex<br>CM13 3BE</p>
                                    <br>
                                    <p>A sales pack containing detailed information regarding the business for sale will be provided to interested parties following the signing and return of a Non-Disclosure Agreement.</p></a>
                                    </td> 
                                </tr>
                            </table>                    


                        <td class="clear-table" width="13px"><img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/10px-spacer.jpg" /></td>                                              

                    </td>
                    </tr>
    </tr> 
</table>


</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed some closing tag and misplaced the closing tag in your HTML part.

I have modified your HTML part and it should be like below.

```
<table class="main" width="804px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tr>
    <td>

        <table width="804px" class="images">
            <tr><td><a target="_blank" href="http://www.wyleshardy.com/businesssales.asp?pge=3"><img style="border: 0; padding: 0" src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/header.jpg" /></a></td></tr>
        </table>            
        <br />

        <table width="804px" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
                <tr>
                    <td class="clear-table" width="20px"><img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/10px-spacer.jpg" /></td>


                    <td class="clear-table" width="395px" valign="top" >
                        <table class="clear-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>                            
                                <td>
                                    <a href="http://www.wyleshardy.com/businesssales.asp?pge=3">
                                    <!-- <ul width="405px">
                                        <li>Company established over 30 years ago.</li>
                                        <li>Trades from NW London from leased industrial premises.</li>
                                        <li>Offers various printing products and services including office stationery, litho printing (44%), digital printing (22%), promotional products and mail fulfilment and dispatch services (34%).</li>
                                        <li>The company has a diverse number of clients, together with a significant business relationship with a high profile client group, forged over many years.</li>
                                        <li>It holds ISO 9001 Certification for quality management and also FSC and PEFC accreditations.</li>
                                        <li>It has a dedicated and loyal workforce, with employees currently totaling 23, including 4 directors.</li>
                                        <li>The business and assets include goodwill (name, web domains, client data base, telephone numbers etc.) Contracts, various items of plant &amp; machinery (some subject to finance agreements), and minimal stock.</li>
                                    </ul> -->
                                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>&bull;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;Company established over 30 years ago.</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>&bull;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;Trades from NW London from leased industrial premises.</td>
                                      </tr>
                                      <tr>
                                        <td>&bull;</td>
                                        <td>&nbsp;Offers various printing products and services including office stationery, litho printing (44%), digital printing (22%), promotional products and mail fulfilment and dispatch services (34%).</td>
                                      </tr>
                                    </table>
                                    </a>
                                    <a href="http://www.wyleshardy.com/businesssales.asp?pge=3"><img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/frplogo.jpg" width="375px" alt="" title="" /></a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>                           

                    </td>                        

                    <td class="clear-table" width="10px"><img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/10px-spacer.jpg" /></td>

                    <td class="content" width="346px" valign="top">
                        <table class="blue-table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                            <tr>
                                <td><a href="http://www.wyleshardy.com/businesssales.asp?pge=3">
                                <p><strong>TURNOVER:</strong> Turnover totalled &pound;2.8m per accounts to June 2013, and &pound; 1.9m for the 9 months to March 2014.</p>
                                <p><strong>OPPORTUNITIES:</strong> The Company offers an excellent opportunity to consolidate existing trade and exploit the contracts already in place.</p>
                                <br>
                                <h1>ENQUIRIES:</h1>
                                <p class="larger">All enquiries should<br>be directed to:<br>
                                <strong>Julie Gearing<br>Nigel Strike<br>FRP Advisory LLP</strong></p>
                                <p><strong>Tel:</strong> 01277 503 304<br><strong>Fax:</strong> 01277 503 300<br><strong>Email:</strong><br> Julie.Gearing@frpadvisory.com<br>Nigel.Strike@frpadvisory.com</p>
                                <br>
                                <p><strong>FRP Advisory LLP</strong><br>Jupiter House<br>Warley Hill Business Park<br>The Drive<br>Brentwood<br>Essex<br>CM13 3BE</p>
                                <br>
                                <p>A sales pack containing detailed information regarding the business for sale will be provided to interested parties following the signing and return of a Non-Disclosure Agreement.</p></a>
                                </td> 
                            </tr>
                        </table>                    
                     </td>

                    <td class="clear-table" width="13px"><img src="http://www.mangemails.co.uk/wyleshardy/28th-May-2014/10px-spacer.jpg" /></td>                                              


                </tr>

</table>
</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Copied directly but unfortunately still having the issue. Uploaded it online for a moment to show new code, fine in browser just not outlook. http://bit.ly/1mEinFQ

Comment: Oh bloody hell, all I needed to do is remove PX from the two width="395px". Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I've now fixed the issue, the changes required were to change the following:

Before

```
width="395px"
```

After

```
width="395"
```